# str_extract_all with decimal numbers

Tags: r, regex, string, text-extraction, data-extraction

I have this dataframe (DF1)

```
structure(list(ID = 1:3, Temperature = c("temp 37.8 37.6", "37,8 was body temperature", "110 kg and 38 temp")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 

ID Temperature
1  "temp 37.8 37.6"
2  "37,8 was body temperature"
3  "110 kg and 38 temp"
```

And this Pattern

```
Pattern <- paste(c("temp", "Temperature"),collapse="|")
```

And I would like to have a new column that contains a number string with decimal number.
Decimal characters are both "," and ".".

So I would like to get this

```
ID Temperature                  Number
1  "temp 37.8 37.6"             c(37.8,37.6)
2  "37,8 was body temperature"  37,8
3  "110 kg and 38 temp"         c(110, 38)
```

I have tried this

```
mutate(Number = ifelse(grepl(Pattern, Temperature), str_extract_all(Temperature, "\\s(.*[0-9])$ | \\s(,*[0-9])$"), "no"))
```

But this regex gives me only an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
stringr::str_extract_all(DF1$Temperature, '\\d+([.,]\\d+)?')

#[[1]]
#[1] "37.8" "37.6"

#[[2]]
#[1] "37,8"

#[[3]]
#[1] "110" "38"
```

where :

`\\d+` - one or more digit followed by

an optional

`[.,]`   dot or comma

`\\d+` - one or more digit.